How can I check if the current environment satisfies a `requirements.txt`?
I have a requirements.txt file. From a shell script, is there any way to determine if the current environment (whatever it might be) satisfies the requirements.txt?
In particular, I don't want to install anything, reach out to the network, or check if updates are available. I'm also not looking for a list of installed packages -- I just want a boolean "is it satisfied".
(My overall goal is to integrate some Python code that has dependencies into a CMake project, either using the current environment if all requirements are satisfied or setting up a venv if not.)
I know several things that don't work:

Running pip freeze and parsing the output tells me the current installed versions, but not if they match the requirements.txt.
The importlib.metadata module gives me the current versions, but not if they match the requirements.txt.
The pip check command tells me if the installed modules have their dependencies, but it doesn't accept a requirements.txt file.
The solutions in this answer don't provide a true/false answer and generally don't parse requirements.txt.


I recommend you start using something like poetry (package management) and miniconda (environment management).

There're 2 schools related to requirements.txt. One teaches that requirements.txt should contain general top-level dependencies with wide range of versions and the output of pip freeze should go to a different file like requirements-freeze.txt. The other school suggests requirements.txt should contain the output of pip freeze and the general top-level dependencies should be in a different file like requirements.in. Which case one is your? (To be continued…)

(…continue) In the 1st case there is no any way to compare the list of installed packages with your requirements.txt because versions of packages (esp. dependencies) could be different. In the second case you need to compare the output of pip freeze with your requirements.txt.

pip install --dry-run -r requirements.txt and check if it wil cahnge anything

Virtual environments are supposed to be somewhat ephemeral. When in doubt, start over.

So I have a big C++ project. We're integrating in some Python that has some dependencies (Sphinx, for documentation). Some devs are "Python-friendly" and will have their own venv's. I want to transparently use their own venv, exactly as expected. But some devs are C++-only (or Python-hostile) and want everything to Just Work. So I want to see if the current environment is sufficient, and if not, set up a new environment.
